# create a histogram using a python list

Tags: python

hello I am trying to create a histogram. 
1. I should read a file with numbers.
2. find the bin with the highst value.
and then try to make a histogram with that numbers.
 
the code below works:

```
def histogram (list):
    for i in list:
        print('*' * i)
histogram([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
```

but the problem is when I want to read a file's number, it gives error. 
what should I do?

when I try to multiply files numbers to '*' it gives the following error.

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: maybe You should tell us what error do You get ?

Comment: Your code works on my python 2.7

Comment: No part of your example is related to reading files; did you leave something out?

Comment: I edited my post. see the error please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

```
def histogram (seq):
    for i in seq:
        print('*' * i, end='\n')
histogram([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
```

#### output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Or better yet, including bins numbers:

```
def histogram (seq):
    for idx, i in enumerate(seq):
        print(idx, '*' * i, end='\n')
histogram([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
```

#### output:

```
0 *
1 **
2 ***
3 ****
4 *****
5 ****
6 ***
7 **
8 *
```

Comment: thank you. how can I read it from file and then print like this?<br>
`dar = open("d:\mass.txt", "r")
cont = dar.read()
print(cont)
def histogram (list):
    for i in list:
        print('*' * int(i))
histogram(cont)`

Comment: Yes, if you are reading the contents from a file, you need to cast to int.

Comment: would you please tell me how?

Comment: casting `variable` to `int` --> `int(variable)`

Comment: how can I find the bin with highest value and then use it as my  Z boson mass measurement?

should I use max?
but in case yes,    how should i use it as a measurement?